# Wordpress AJAX file uploadernot working on WAMP?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

```
    var file = document.getElementById("genomeFile").files[0];

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("action", 'upload_file');
    formdata.append("genomeFile", file);

    var upload = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_data.ajax_url,
        data: formdata,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false, 
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { console.log(data);             }

    });
```

But the problem is console.log(data); just outputs 0. Heres the PHP function:

```
public function upload_file() {

    die('test');

    $file = $_FILES["genomeFile"];
    $uploader = get_current_user_id();

    require_once(GENOMICS__PLUGIN_DIR . 'classes/uploadGenome.class.php'); 
    $uploadGenome = new uploadGenome();
    $uploadGenome->upload($file);

    die();
}
```

"test" doesn't get outputted, so the request isn't reaching the upload_file() function. The code works on MAMP Pro and LAMP servers, its just WAMP thats not working. Anyone know how to fix or diagnose this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that post_max_size in php.ini was set to 3M. I changed it to **post_max_size = 100M** and now it works.